# Load XML into dropdownlist C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to add all the city names into a dropdownlist. In my code I only get the first name loaded. How do I change the code so that I get all?

My XML:

```
<country>
  <city>
    <cityname>Cannes</cityname>
    <cityid>123</cityid>
  </city>
  <city>
    <cityname>Paris</cityname>
    <cityid>123</cityid>
  </city>
  <city>
    <cityname>Nice</cityname>
    <cityid>123</cityid>
  </city>
  <city>
    <cityname>Marseilles</cityname>
    <cityid>123</cityid>
  </city>
</country>
```

My code:

```
XElement country= XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("myXML.xml"));


foreach (XElement name in country.Element("city").Elements("cityname"))
{
  dropdownList.Items.Add(name.Value);
}
```

Comment: You are missing a plural "s" in your loops city getting.

Comment: You need to get the nodes of `country` and then iterate through the `city` entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a simple 'S' in your code.

I've just tested it and this works:

```
XElement country= XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("myXML.xml"));

foreach (XElement name in country.Elements("city").Elements("cityname"))
{
  dropdownList.Items.Add(name.Value);
}
```

Kind regards,